# Citations in table appearing first

Tags: citing

I am using \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} and I have tried unsrt as well. I have a table in Section 2 of my document which has a lot of citations. These citations get numbered from [1] onward, instead of references cited in Section 1 appearing first. Comprehensive search on SE didn't yield an answer. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are the citations in the table in Section 2 of the document by any chance contained in the table's `\caption` -- and does your document feature a list of tables?

Comment: No. The table itself consists of references. A lot of them in each row. There is no reference in the caption.

Comment: Please post the table code.

Comment: It was too long and couldn't post here. Here is the outline.\begin{table*}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{.....}
\label{tableReferences}
\begin{tabular}{||c|c||}
  \hline

  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*} There are many references like \cite{..} in each row

Comment: I'm afraid the outline itself is not helpful.